# window displaying graphics instead of being blank

Tags: java, methods

After importing Graphics and adding the paint method, the window display suddenly became a copier. It displayed any graphics and text of what was behind it. The window does show the string but it's hard to see as there is text overlaying it.
Before adding Graphics, the window was fine. What is the issue? Thanks for help.

```
package gamenew.Comstock;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class JavaGame extends JFrame {

public JavaGame() {                     
    setTitle("Aetas Sterci");
    setSize(500, 500);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //ends prog cleanly
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {                    //text string and position 
    g.drawString("Showing Some Strings", 75, 75);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new JavaGame();              


}
```

}

Comment: It is probably a good idea to use a JPanel.

Comment: It is more than a good idea. See the Custom Painting tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Before adding Graphics, the window was fine. What is the issue?

Don't override the paint() method of a JFrame!!!

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the proper way to do this.

Comment: As has been stated here and elsewhere again, again, and again. RTFT. 1+